# Manipulating sets in dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, set

I need to update a dictionary with the use of sets that I have. My program needs to essentially take a set and assign it to a value (in a dictionary). If the set already exists, i need to update its value (keep adding the values together).

Here is how my program works now:

```
    for line in fd:
    new_line = line.split(' ')
    for word in new_line:
        new_word = ''.join(l for l in word if l.isalpha())
        new_word = new_word.lower()
        ind_count = 0
        for let in new_word:
            c_dict[let, ind_count] = new_word
            ind_count += 1
```

And in my `fd` file, it contains a list of words.

I want my result to look something like this:

```
print(c_dict)

{ (0, "h") : { "hello", "helps" } , (0, "c") : { "cow" } }
```

This essentially takes a letter from the word and it's index #, and sets the value to that word. My file will have hundreds of words that have the letter 'h' at position 0, and essentially the key (0, 'h') would have a value that contains all of those words.

Right now, my program just replaces the values. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want the values of the dictionary to be sets (i.e. with no repeated words), or lists of every occurrence of the relevant words?

Comment: I want the values to be sets. If a word occurs twice, it will simply only have one occurrence of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`dict.setdefault()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) is perfect for this:

```
for line in fd:
    new_line = line.split(' ')
    for word in new_line:
        new_word = ''.join(l for l in word if l.isalpha())
        new_word = new_word.lower()
        for ind_count, let in enumerate(new_word):
            c_dict.setdefault((let, ind_count), set()).add(new_word)
```

Note that I also change the innermost for loop to use [`enumerate()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) rather than manually incrementing `ind_index` inside the loop.

`c_dict.setdefault((let, ind_count), set()).add(new_word)` is equivalent in behavior to the following code:

```
if (let, ind_count) in c_dict:
    c_dict[let, ind_count].add(new_word)
else:
    c_dict[let, ind_count] = set([new_word])
```